# Calculate and determine characteristic curve \$ U_{DAC}\$

Tags: dac, counter

A DAC circuit. Calculate \$ U_{DAC}\$ and its characteristic curve after 16 pulses.

[image]

Know,

\$ Q_A, D_0\$: LSB;  \$ Q_D, D_3\$: MSB

\$U_{DAC}=0.1N_x\$ (\$N_x \$ is value input of DAC)

IC74191 is 4 bit synchronous up counters and initial value of counter is 0.

I think that after 16 pulses, \$ Q_A=Q_B=Q_C=Q_C=0\$, so \$U_{DAC}=0.1N_x\$,but I'm not sure. I also don''t know how to draw characteristic curve \$ U_{DAC}\$

Comment: Since this is a homework question we will expect you to show us that you have made a substantial effort to solve this yourself, show us your work, and then ask a **specific question**. If you don't know what a "characteristic curve" is then you should ask your instructor.

Comment: A DAC converts digital numbers into analog voltages. Can you draw a graph of this conversion?

Comment: when using 16 pulses, i think the result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQYyI.png

Comment: @Jens, it means after each pulse, I calculate a \$U_{DAC}\$ in graph???

Comment: There is no characteristic curve "after" 16 pulses. I think, the intended task is to calculate the voltage steps "during" 16 pulses.